# When using function.apply(this, arguments) order of arguments gets mixed

Tags: javascript

So I was trying to 'inherit' parameters in someway and I came across the use of

`function.apply(this, arguments)`

And it did the job... well for the most part. What I am getting is that when I'm calling a function from the parent object the arguments of the parent function get in front of the others and when I call a function from the inheritor they don't.

Here's my code:

```
function Human(name, gender, tel, address){
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.address = address;
    this.tel = tel;
}

Human.prototype.introduce = function(){
    console.log("Hi I'm " + this.name + " a " + this.gender + " from " + this.address + 
    ". My number is " + this.tel);
}

    Student.prototype = new Human; 
    Student.prototype.constructor = Student;


function Student(school,marks){
    Human.apply(this, arguments);
    this.school = school;
    this.marks = marks;

}

Student.prototype.average = function(){
    this.total = 0;
    this.average = 0;
    this.markslength = this.marks.length;
    for(var i = 0; i<this.markslength; i++){
        this.total = this.total + this.marks[i]
    }
    this.average = (this.total)/(this.markslength);

    var marks3 = [6,6,2]
    var Nasko = new Student('Nasko', 'Male', 14421687, 'Sofia', 'FELS', marks3);
```

And when I do: `console.log(Nasko.name);` It's OK.
But when I do `console.log(Nasko.average());` It gives me NaN.
So my question is - how to actually 'fix' it

Sorry if I asked an already asked question but I couldn't really think of how to ask it in any short a redirection to another similar post will be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you expecting the first four arguments of `new` to be applied to `Human`, and the last two to `Student`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using first two arguments for school and marks which actually name and gender.

You can use arguments for reading last values

```
function Student(){
    Human.apply(this, arguments);
     var len = arguments.length;
    this.school = arguments[arguments.length-2]; // second last argument is school
    this.marks =  arguments[arguments.length-1]; // last argument is mark.

}
```

Comment: Thank you that did it and sounds logical, just didn't know I could use it.

Comment: This would work, but it's confusing to keep the argument names this way. It would make more sense to extend the `Human` signature.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that but the Student class only should have school and marks because there are other humans - and they shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

The value of two parameters named `"school"` and `"marks"` in the `"Student"` constructor will be "Nasko" and "Male" and in the `"Human"` class you are passing "Nasko" as `"name"` and "Male" as `"gender"`. I think you are confused with the apply and passing arguments to it a little bit. Of course after initializing the code marks is a string value of "Male" and you cannot have the average result.

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: Yeah I realized what actually happens just didn't know how to fix it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The only difference between "call" and "apply" functions is the arguments you are passing to them. I thing you should take a look at "call" function. It's more static but easy to read and understand. Cheers